# Storing a string in a var, gives error due to concatination?

Tags: php, html, variables

I am doing the following in my PHP

```
public $message = "<p>A new user has requested to signup for Company Name</p>
                   <p><strong>Name:</strong>". $name ."</p>
                   <p><strong>Email Address:</strong>" . $email . "</p>
                   <p><strong>Contact Number:</strong>" . $contact_number . "</p>
                   <p>Please check the attached file, for further details.</p>
                   <p>Thanks,<br/>Company Name Email Centre</p>";
```

As you can see I am tring to create a small segment of HTML interspersed with some PHP variables, however I am getting the following error,

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';'

It says this on line 31 which is the second `<p>` tag, however I cannot see a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public $message= "<p>A new user has requested to signup for Company Name</p>\
                   <p><strong>Name:</strong>". $name ."</p>\
                   <p><strong>Email Address:</strong>" . $email . "</p>\
                   <p><strong>Contact Number:</strong>" . $contact_number . "</p>\
                   <p>Please check the attached file, for further details.</p>\
                   <p>Thanks,<br/>Company Name Email Centre</p>";


/* Try this it will work ... ( u need to escape lines using \ ) */
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not use var/string concatenation  in a class var definition. Why don't you write a method such as `getMessage()` or `printMessage()` or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

PHP terminates a string at newline. You need to concatenate everytime a newline begins:

```
public $message = "<p>A new user has requested to signup for Company Name</p>"
                   ."<p><strong>Name:</strong>". $name ."</p>"
                   ."<p><strong>Email Address:</strong>" . $email . "</p>"
                   ."<p><strong>Contact Number:</strong>" . $contact_number . "</p>"
                   ."<p>Please check the attached file, for further details.</p>"
                   ."<p>Thanks,<br/>Company Name Email Centre</p>";
```

Comment: Or just use single quotes (`'`) instead of double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way. and have a look at http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php

```
public $message = "<p>A new user has requested to signup for Company Name</p>" .
                  "<p><strong>Name:</strong>". $name ."</p>" . 
                  "<p><strong>Email Address:</strong>" . $email . "</p>" .
                  "<p><strong>Contact Number:</strong>" . $contact_number . "</p>" .
                  "<p>Please check the attached file, for further details.</p>" .
                  "<p>Thanks,<br/>Company Name Email Centre</p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in a class attribute definition, instead define the attribute then give it a value in the class constructor:

```
class Test {
    public $message;
    public $name = 'Demo Name';
    public function __construct() {
        $this->message = 'anything you want' . $this->name; # etc
    }
}
```

In the actual definition you can only give litterals, no variable evaluations.

Cheers